# Add <LinkedList> to previous Queue class of Objects

Tags: java, object, linked-list, queue

I have written an ObjectQueue class to handle objects, but i would like to also be able to handle LinkedList types, so that i will have a queue of objects using a linked list.  is this even possible?

basically i want something similar to

```
ArrayList<LinkedList <Job> > data
```

except with: `ObjectQueue<LinkedList <Job> > data`

how could i modify my class:

```
public class ObjectQueue {
      private Object[] item;
      private int front;
      private int rear;
      private int size;


    public ObjectQueue() {
        size = 100;
        item = new Object[size];
        front = size-1;
        rear  = size-1;
    }

    public ObjectQueue(int max) {
        size = max;
        item = new Object[size];
        front = size-1;
        rear  = size-1;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return front == rear;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
       return rear == size-1 ? front == 0 : front == rear+1;
    }

    public void clear() {
        front = size-1;
        rear  = size-1;
    }


    public void insert(Object x) {
        if (isFull()) {
            System.out.println("Insert Runtime Error: Queue Overflow");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (rear == size-1)         // or rear = (rear+1) % size;
            rear = 0;
        else
            rear++;
        item[rear] = x;
    }

    public Object remove() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Remove Runtime Error: Queue Underflow");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (front == size-1)            // or front = (front+1) % size;
            front = 0;
        else
            front++;
        return item[front];
    }

    public Object query() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Query Runtime Error: Queue Underflow");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (front == size-1)
            return item[0];
        else
            return item[front+1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to replace the array with a LinkedList, or do you want to specify the type of objects going in the ObjectQueue so they are specifically LinkedList? Because you seem to oppose "objects" and "LinkedLists"...

Comment: i guess what i am trying to do is have a queue of objects stored in a linkedlist,  there may be more than one way to do this but i wanted to use my ObjectQueue class in a different new way...

Comment: Since [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implements [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) (there are other implementations as well in the JDK), do you actually need your ObjectQueue? If it's entirely there, its feature set seems to be a subset of the actual Queues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your class generic:

```
public class ObjectQueue<T> {
    ...
    public void insert(T x) {
        ...
    }
    public T remove() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: i was able to modify the class using the generic idea above, however how can i convert item = new Object[size]; ???

i tried "item=new LinkedList<T>(size); and got a constructor error...

Comment: @user1660948 You can't specify the size of a LinkedList, since it's a linked list... It's not preallocated.

Comment: ahh. ok. then that is an unnecessary declaration.  thanks Frank